# Select MAX of multiple Attributes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that contains 3000 attributes (its for a data mining experiment)
The table looks like

```
id attr1 attr2, attr3
a  0         1       0
a  1         0       0
a  0         0       0
a  0         0       1
```

I wish to have it in the format

```
id, attr1, attr2, attr3
a     1       1        1
```

The values can only be 0 or 1 so, i think just getting the max of each column and grouping it by the ID would achieve this
However, i don't wish to Type MAX (attr X) for each and every attribute
Does anyone know a quick way of implementing this

Thank you very much for your help in advance

Answer (score 3):

This is easy enough with `group by`:

```
select id, max(attr1) as attr1, max(attr2) as attr2, max(attr3) as attr3
from t
group by id
```

If you don't want to do all this typing, put your list of columns in Excel.  Add in a formula such as `="      max("&A1&") as "&A1&","`.  Then copy the cell down and copy the result to where your query is.

You can also do this in SQL, with something like:

```
select '      max('||column_name||') as '||column_name||','
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns c
where table_name = <your table name here> and column_name like 'attr%'
```

When you do these last two, remember to remove the final comma from the last row.

Comment: Hi Gordon, It never even occurred to me about the excel method. This will save me loads of time. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some aggregating function in order to use attributes which are not in the group statement. So there is no any quicker way.